# Characteristics of plasma accelerators

Tags: plasma-physics, particle-accelerators

I've been reading about plasma accelerators but I do not understand the main differences between a plasma accelerator and a "normal" one. In the case of LHC for example, if we have free protons accelerated, wouldn't that be a plasma?
In any case, do plasma accelerators have any advantages with respect to other type of accelerators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between "normal" Radiofrequency (RF) accelerators and plasma based accelerators is how the acceleration happens, it's not really to do with the beam itself.

In a RF accelerator, particles are in a tube which is in vacuum and they are pushed by the electric field of radio waves. The limit to this is that the strongest possible electric field you can use is about 100 million Volts per meter. Beyond that, the electric field of the waves start to ionise and rip apart the walls of the accelerator pipe which disrupts the electric field accelerating the particles and can result in poor beam quality and potential collisions between the particle beam and the accelerator beam pipe.

Plasma on the other hand is already a fully ionised, ripped apart and broken material so it can sustain huge electric fields and nothing happens to it. Plasma accelerators use laser pulses (or occasionally particle beams) to create a wave inside the plasma by pushing electrons away from their starting position and allowing the protons left behind pull them back towards where they started. This wave travels behind the laser like a wave behind a boat.
If the conditions are correct, some electrons can become trapped inside the wave where they surf it, gaining a large amount of energy in a small distance. The accelerating electric field of the plasma wave can easily reach > 100 Billion Volts per meter so to reach the same particle energy, a plasma accelerator can be 1/1000  th the size of a RF accelerator.